# Adding a column and updating all records using knex and postgres

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I need to add a column to my table of riders, allowing us to store the name of the image that will display on that rider's card. I then need to update all of the records with the auto-generated image names.

I've done a bunch of searching, and all roads seem to lead back to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543668/batch-update-in-knex) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39760408/run-update-inside-knex-migration). I've tried the code from both of these threads, swapping in my own table and column names, but I still can't get it to work.

This is the latest version of the code:

```
export async function up(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.transaction(trx => {
    const riders = [
        {
          name: 'Fabio Quartararo',
          card: 'rider_card_FabioQuartararo'
        },
        ...24 other riders here...
        {
          name: 'Garrett Gerloff',
          card: 'rider_card_GarrettGerloff'
        },
    ];
    return knex.schema.table('riders', (table) => table.string('card')).transacting(trx)
      .then(() =>{
        const queries = [];
        riders.forEach(rider => {
            const query = knex('riders')
                .update({
                    card: rider.card
                })
                .where('name', rider.name)
                .transacting(trx); // This makes every update be in the same transaction
            queries.push(query);
        });
    
        Promise.all(queries) // Once every query is written
          .then(() => trx.commit) // We try to execute all of them
          .catch(() => trx.rollback); // And rollback in case any of them goes wrong
      });
  });
}
```

When I run the migration, however, it fails with the following error:

```
migration file "20211202225332_update_rider_card_imgs.js" failed
migration failed with error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'all')    
Error running migrations:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'all')
    at D:\Users\seona\Documents\_Blowfish\repos\MotoGP\dist\database\migrations\20211202225332_update_rider_card_imgs.js:134:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

So it's clearly having **some** sort of problem with `Promise.all()`, but I can't for the life of me figure out what. Searching has not turned up any useful results.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I can get this working? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be following some older documentation and/or examples (at least that's what I was doing).

The `Promise` argument is no longer passed into the migration `up` and `down` functions.

So, the signature should be something like this:

```
 function up(knex) {
    // Use the built in Promise class
    Promise.all(<ARRAY_OF_QUERY_PROMISES>);
    ...
  }
```